# BigCommerce California Responsive Mobile rendering issues

Tags: css, responsive-design, themes, responsive, bigcommerce

So I have a question regarding the rendering of my BigComemrce theme on mobile and tablet devices.
If you go to [findmethatwine.com](http://findmethatwine.com) on desktop you will see beside the menu options 2 content sections 1 for free delivery and 1 for a money back guarantee.

From what I can see these are made up of the below "pagemenu" div classes.  My issue is that I cannot figure out how to replicate this in the mobile version of the theme properly.  When trying I can get the content to appear, but no amount of tinkering with sizes that I can do will allow the content to sit neatly in that blank space I have created beside that logo on the mobile sized rendering. (for details of how I moved that logo over see this post [Responsive design on California Responsive BigCommerce template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273590/responsive-design-on-california-responsive-bigcommerce-template/43277024?noredirect=1#comment73641365_43277024)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or guidance for a novice but enthusiastic holder of a website!

```
<div class="PageMenu">%%Panel.PagesMenu%%</div>

<div class="PageMenu" style="width: 200px; color: #f3f3f3; font-weight: bold;text-align:center;">
      <img src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-yg07p8k5b4/product_images/uploaded_images/free-delivery.png?t=1477562519" border="0" id="LogoImage" alt="Free Delivery (minimum purchase applies)">
      Spend £150 or<br> buy 12 bottles
</div>

<div class="PageMenu" style="width: 200px; color: #f3f3f3; font-weight: bold;text-align:center;">
    No quibble money back Guarantee. We will uplift and refund your unwanted bottles* 
</div>
```

Comment: do you want something like this ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMfhS.png

Comment: Exactly like this @SahilDhir  Obviously in terms of space I can adjust text and images used etc to get it fitting, readable etc etc obviously. Just struggling to figure out the correct code I need to insert then I can figure out exactly where to insert it with trial and error.

Comment: Check the answer and add the css

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following css in your responsive.css and it adjust accordingly. Since styles are added inline so in few attributes I have to use !important;**

```
@media  screen and (max-width: 767px){
#Header .Content .PageMenu:nth-child(2) {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 80px;
            right: 0px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            display: block !important;
            color: #000 !important;
            /* width: 100px !important; */
}

#Header .Content .PageMenu:nth-child(3) {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 70px;
            display: block !important;
            color: #000 !important;
        }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful @SahilDhir.  Just one issue now on just the smallest of screen sizes once you get below about 538 pixels the 2 elements start to overlap each other. Perhaps I can set something to prioritise the free Delivery message and loose the other?  Is this Z-Index?

Comment: Sorry one more issue when scrolling down the screen these images stay static covering the content? I would prefer they stay at the top of the page within that menu bar area, not scrolling down the creen

Comment: For issue 1- you can decrease there width and font sizes to acheive the desired result.

Comment: For issue 2- Its happening because those 2 elements are inside the header div which is fixed.. You have to make a similar approach like you did for your logo.. i.e only for mobile these 2 divs will come seperately outside the header

Comment: Thanks again @SahilDhir.  Issue 1 Sorted I repeated your code and changed nth child(3) to display none when screen size was max 565px.

Comment: Issue 2, I hear and understand what you are saying. I did not make the template it is a bought theme so I am not 100% sure how to achieve this.  So any further guidance (I know I am asking a huge amount) would be really appreciated.

Comment: I can fix the problem. But without seeing into the code I can only guide you on how to achieve this.